# SQL - Selecting DATE FORMAT from table and displaying on screen

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have inserte date into my table and it is in the format YYYY-MM-DD, However when displaying this information I would like to display the date the in DD-MM-YYY format. If anyone has an idea how to achieve this please let me know. Please see my sql query below as this query it not working.

```
  // Create query using SQL string
  $sql_query = "SELECT title, level, DATE_FORMAT(dateTo, '%W %M %e 
   %Y') 
     FROM jobPost ORDER BY jobID DESC";

  // Query database using connection
 $result = $conn->query($sql_query);
```

Comment: Please add expected output. Take current date as an example.

Comment: What is wrong with your query?

Comment: Don't do formatting in your data layer.  In the database a date is a date is a date, it doesn't have a format until you turn it in to a string.  Allow your SQL to return an actual date data type to your client, be that PHP or Python or a reporting tool, then use the client's native abilities to format the data however you like.  Don't pass around dates as strings just so you can pre-format them.  Next you'll want to turn numbers in to strings so that you can add leading 0's.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
DATE_FORMAT(dateTo, '%d-%m-%Y')
/* For dateTo value of 2018-11-13, it will output 13-11-2018 */
```

Details:

- `%d`     Day of the month as a numeric value (01 to 31)
- `%m`     Month name as a numeric value (00 to 12)
- `%Y`     Year as a numeric, 4-digit value

Check the complete list of available format specifiers at: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: $sql_query = "SELECT title, level, DATE_FORMAT(dateTo, '%d-%m-%Y') FROM jobPost ORDER BY jobID DESC";  

Getting value NULL.

Comment: @AdamMcMenamin ?

Comment: When displaying information on my page, I am getting value 'NULL' from your query.

Comment: @AdamMcMenamin check if you have value in `dateTo` field ?